# Facebook 'Like' button code generator not working?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm trying to generate Facebook 'Like' button code for a URL from here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

I've tried all kinds of URLs (including www.google.com) and configurations.
Each time I click 'Get Code' a window opens for a second then disappears.
If I right click to 'Open in new Tab' it says 'Sorry, something went wrong - We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can ..'

Is this problem occurring for everyone or just me?

Note: I've tried this on multiple devices also ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its  a facebook bug, I've reported this here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/291880324304391/

You can subscribe to get any update on this.

**Edit:**

This issue is now fixed. :)